# Draw selected areas of a UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage

I have a UIImage containing an image with a whole bunch of smaller pictures on the image (essentially an image strip containing sprites). I'd like to draw a single sprite onto an area of my UIView.

I can't seem to find a way draw only part of the UIImage onto the view. Is there a method that does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-SW1). You can get a `CGImage` from a `UIImage` with the [property of the same name](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/CGImage).

EDIT: another option that exists in 2014, that did not in 2009, is [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Depending on what you might be doing that needs a sprite sheet, that might be useful.

Comment: Good one @Sixten, I think this sounds more like what he wanted +1

Comment: Works perfectly (minus some headaches with CGImages being flipped while drawing). Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a UIImage category for handling sprite sheets. Check out this, it may be helpful [http://reecon.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/uiimage-sprite-additions-objective-c/](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/uiimage-sprite-additions-objective-c/)

Comment: This approach impacts performance in case the drawing is intensive. Is there a way without recreating parts of the image but just use available bitmap data from the giving UIImage instance?

Comment: The wording of the documentation strongly suggests to me that this function _does_ reuse the existing bitmap data, and just changes the bounds of what parts of that data are "in" the image. But certainly there are Quartz functions to get at the underlying bitmap data.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a `UIImage` category for handling sprite sheets. Check this out, it may be helpful http://reecon.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/uiimage-sprite-additions-objective-c/

As noted earlier, this category bases on `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` but makes the process of extracting sprites from a single sprite sheet far **more convenient** and **faster**.

Link to git hub page: 
https://github.com/r3econ/UIImage-Sprite-Additions

You can also install using cocoa pods.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you sure can with Quartz.

There is a tutorial here that shows you how to take a UIImage and mask a part of it.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Here is the code from that page (incase it goes down for some reason)

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Comment: This is great stuff and I'll definitely bookmark it but I don't want to create a mask for this. I simply want to do something like: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage"] drawInRect:CGMakeRect(10,10,50,50) fromRect:CGMakeRect(60,60,50,50)];